# How to stop a UserControl (nee ScrollableControl) from calling ScrollWindow?

Tags: .net, scroll, scrollable

The .NET [`UserControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.usercontrol.aspx) (which descends from [`ScrollableControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol.aspx)) has to ability to display horizontal and vertical scrollbars.

The caller can set the visibility, and range, of these horizontal and vertical scrollbars:

```
UserControl.AutoScroll = true;
UserControl.AutoScrollMinSize = new Size(1000, 4000); //1000x4000 scroll area
```

> **Note:** The `UserControl` (i.e. `ScrollableControl`) uses the Windows standard mechanism of specifying `WS_HSCROLL` and `WS_VSCROLL` window styles to make scrollbars appear. That is: they do not create separate Windows or .NET scroll controls, positioning them at the right/bottom of the window. Windows has a standard mechanism for displaying one, or both, scrollbars.

If the user scrolls the control, the `UserControl` is sent a `WM_HSCROLL` or `WM_VSCROLL` message. In response to these messages i want the ScrollableControl to invalidate the client area, which is what would happen in native Win32:

```
switch (uMsg) 
{ 
   case WM_VSCROLL:
       ...
       GetScrollInfo(...);
       ...
       SetScrollInfo(...);
       ...

       InvalidateRect(g_hWnd, 
              null, //erase entire client area
              true, //background needs erasing too (trigger WM_ERASEBKGND));
       break;
 }
```

i need the entire client area invalidated. The problem is that **UserControl** (i.e. `ScrollableControl`) [calls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol.setdisplayrectlocation.aspx) the [`ScrollWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787591%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API function:

```
protected void SetDisplayRectLocation(int x, int y)
{
    ...
    if ((nXAmount != 0) || ((nYAmount != 0) && base.IsHandleCreated))
    {
        ...
        SafeNativeMethods.ScrollWindowEx(new HandleRef(this, base.Handle), nXAmount, nYAmount, null, ref rectClip, NativeMethods.NullHandleRef, ref prcUpdate, 7);
    }
    ...
}
```

Rather than triggering an InvalidateRect on the entire client rectangle, ScrollableControl tries to "*salvage*" the existing content in the client area. For example, the user scrolls **up**, the current client content is pushed **down** by `ScrollWindowEx`, and then only the newly uncovered area is invalidated, triggering a `WM_PAINT`:

[image]

In the above diagram, the checkerboard area is the content that is **invalid** and will have to be painted during the next WM_PAINT.

In my case this is no good; the top of my control contains a "header" (e.g. listview column headers). Scrolling this content further down is incorrect:

[image]

and it causes visual corruption.

i want the ScrollableControl to **not** use `ScrollWindowEx`, but instead just invalidate the entire client area.

i tried overriding `OnScroll` protected method:

```
protected override void OnScroll(ScrollEventArgs se)
{
   base.OnScroll(se);

   this.Invalidate();
}
```

But it causes an double-draw.

> **Note:** i could use double-buffering to mask the problem, but that's not a real solution
>
> - double buffering should not be used under remote desktop/terminal session
> - it's wasteful of CPU resources
> - it's not the question i'm asking

i considered using a `Control` instead of `UserControl` (i.e. before `ScrollableControl` in the inheritance chain) and manually add a HScroll or VScroll .NET control - but that's not desirable either:

- Windows already provides a standard look for the position of scrollbars (it's not trivial to duplicate)
- that is a lot of functionality to have to reproduce from scratch, when i only want it to **InvalidateRect** rather than **ScrollWindowEx**

Since i can see, and posted, the code internal to `ScrollableControl` i know there is no property to disable use of `ScrollWindow`, but is there a property to disable the use of `ScrollWindow`?

---

### Update:

i tried overriding the offending method, and using reflector to steal all the code:

```
protected override void SetDisplayRectLocation(int x, int y)
{
    ...
    Rectangle displayRect = this.displayRect;
    ...
    this.displayRect.X = x;
    this.displayRect.Y = y;
    if ((nXAmount != 0) || ((nYAmount != 0) && base.IsHandleCreated))
    {
        ...
        SafeNativeMethods.ScrollWindowEx(new HandleRef(this, base.Handle), nXAmount, nYAmount, null, ref rectClip, NativeMethods.NullHandleRef, ref prcUpdate, 7);
    }
    ...
}
```

The problem is that [SetDisplayRectLocation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol.setdisplayrectlocation.aspx) reads and writes to a private member variable (`displayRect`). Unless Microsoft changes C# to allow descendants access to private members: i cannot do that.

---

### Update Two

i realized that copy-pasting the implementation of `ScrollableControl`, fixing the one *issue* means i will also have to copy-n-paste the entire inheritance chain down to `UserControl`

```
...
   ScrollableControl2 : Control, IArrangedElement, IComponent, IDisposable
      ContainerControl2 : ScrollableControl2, IContainerControl
         UserControl2 : ContainerControl2
```

i'd really prefer to work **with** object-oriented design, rather than against it.

Comment: Could you provide screenshots without swear words?

Comment: There you go; virgin eyes saved.

Comment: Good question. You've probably tried many of the things I would. I assume you've tried to override WndPrc and intercepting both the scroll message and the paint messages?

Comment: @Pedery i thought about that, but then i would still be faced with having to reimplement a lot of processing. My best bet is to simply override the offending protected `SetDisplayLocation` method, not calling `base`, and copy-pasting the entire guts except for the one line. Downside of that solution is a) i'd prefer to work *with* the .NET `UserControl` (if possible), not against it, b) copying the current implementation i will lose any future .NET enchancements to `ScrollableControl`, and c) although i don't care: it's not legal

Comment: Yep, I see. I'd have to play around with this myself to try to come up with a solution. You seem to be very on par with the possibilities and limitations of .Net so I think your attempts are just as good as mine. Good luck!

Comment: In typical OO fashion: the protected `SetDisplayLocation` method uses a private `displayRect` member - there's no way to reimplement the method without access to that private member.

Comment: @Ian, if I understand correctly, you do the entire inside-painting job yourself (as in you don't place other controls inside the scrollable area), so "reinventing the wheel" here is really not that much to do, and it will give you full control of the areas you want to render. If you do have inner-controls (other than the headers) than it's a bit trickier, but you can only scroll one big container control instead of manipulating the positions of each control. I would choose (and have chosen before...) one of those options.

Comment: Very well written, detailed post. I'm having exactly the same problem but I doubt very much if I could have enunciated it as well. It would be nice if Microsoft would provide an option to control this aspect of ScrollableControl.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem, thanks for posting this.  I may have found a solution to your problem.  My solution is to overload WndProc in order to handle the scroll messages, turn off redraw while calling the base class handler, then force a redraw of the entire window after the message has been handled.  This solution appears to work ok:

```
    private void sendRedrawMessage( bool redrawFlag )
    {
        const int WM_SETREDRAW = 0x000B;

        IntPtr wparam = new IntPtr( redrawFlag ? 1 : 0 );
        Message msg = Message.Create( Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, wparam, IntPtr.Zero );
        NativeWindow.FromHandle( Handle ).DefWndProc( ref msg );
    }

    protected override void WndProc( ref Message m )
    {
        switch ( m.Msg )
        {
            case 276: // WM_HSCROLL
            case 277: // WM_VSCROLL
                sendRedrawMessage( false );
                base.WndProc( ref m );
                sendRedrawMessage( true );
                Refresh(); // Invalidate all
                return;
        }

        base.WndProc( ref m );
    }
```

I thought of trying this because of the suggestion to overload WndProc combined with your observation that you can't overload SetDisplayRectLocation.  I thought that disabling WM_PAINT during the UserControl's handling of the scroll event might work.

Hope this helps.

Tom

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly!
You might want to handle WM_MOUSEWHEEL in the same way, also; just add "case 522: // WM_MOUSEWHEEL" to the switch in WndProc()

Comment: @Ricardo. Nice. I'm using mouse wheel to control image zoom and that's exactly the scenario where I need to avoid ScrollWindowEx.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried getting in contact with a programmer from Microsoft?  I'm sure if you contact microsoft you could post your question to them, perhaps even get phone support.

Here is a link to support for the .NET framework: [click here](https://support.microsoft.com/oas/default.aspx?gprid=548&st=1&wfxredirect=1&sd=gn).  It mentions that you can get in contact with .NET support professionals by email, phone, or online.

Answer (score 0):

Tom's solution is awesome, but I think there is an opportunity for a small optimization. 
Without Tom's two methods, when I cause scrolling, for example, by clicking a scroll-bar endpoint, my onPaint sees a single invocation.
When I add Tom's two methods, my onPaint starts getting two invocations for the
same scroll bar positions.
The solution for me seemed to be to ignore the final SB_ENDSCROLL that occurs is the scrolling operations. With this I stopped seeing duplicate paints at the same scroll location.

```
private void sendRedrawMessage(bool redrawFlag)
{
    const int WM_SETREDRAW = 0x000B;

    IntPtr wparam = new IntPtr(redrawFlag ? 1 : 0);
    Message msg = Message.Create(Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, wparam, IntPtr.Zero);
    NativeWindow.FromHandle(Handle).DefWndProc(ref msg);
}

protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    switch (m.Msg)
    {
        case 276: // WM_HSCROLL
        case 277: // WM_VSCROLL
            if ((ushort)m.WParam == 8) // SB_ENDSCROLL ignore scroll bar release
                break;
            sendRedrawMessage(false);
            base.WndProc(ref m);
            sendRedrawMessage(true);
            Refresh(); // Invalidate all
            return;
    }

    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Comment: I think if you make that optimization, the the window does not properly repaint after using the buttons on the ends of the scroll bars. At least that seemed to be my experience.

Answer (score 0):

I also try to disable calling that ScrollWindowEx().
In Current version of ScrollableControl, On WmVScroll(), ScrollWindowEx() is called like this:

```
protected void SetDisplayRectLocation(int x, int y)
{
    ...
    if (num != 0 || (num2 != 0 && base.IsHandleCreated))
    {
        Rectangle clientRectangle2 = base.ClientRectangle;
        NativeMethods.RECT rectClip = NativeMethods.RECT.FromXYWH(clientRectangle2.X, clientRectangle2.Y, clientRectangle2.Width, clientRectangle2.Height);
        NativeMethods.RECT prcUpdate = NativeMethods.RECT.FromXYWH(clientRectangle2.X, clientRectangle2.Y, clientRectangle2.Width, clientRectangle2.Height);
        SafeNativeMethods.ScrollWindowEx(new HandleRef(this, base.Handle), num, num2, null, ref rectClip, NativeMethods.NullHandleRef, ref prcUpdate, 7);
    }
    ...
}
```

And SetDisplayRectLocation() is called from Wm?Scroll() like this:

```
private void WmVScroll(ref Message m)
{
    ...
    if (GetScrollState(16) || flag)
    {
        SetScrollState(8, value: true);
        SetDisplayRectLocation(displayRect.X, -num);
        SyncScrollbars(AutoScroll);
    }
    WmOnScroll(ref m, oldValue, num, ScrollOrientation.VerticalScroll);
}
```

So, I try to call

```
 SetScrollState( 16, false )
```

to prevent calling SetDisplayRectLocation(). And it works.

But one new problem is found. Number 16 is defined ScrollStateFullDrag in ScrollableControl. When this state is disabled, Scrollbar position is not updated while user drags thumbs.

So, I need to get scroll event, and in the event, save current scroll position to local variable and Invalidate control. On OnPaint(), it draws based on the local variable, not base on the scroll position.

I try some tests, but until now, it's ok and working correctly.